# custom when statement not firing functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a when statement but it is not working as planned. Basically its a function to call another function when try. First before I explain further here is the syntax

```
when(function() {
    //code here
});
```

Now basically... Think this way.. We have a progressbar.. We also have a custom event such as...

```
var pBarEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
pBarEvent.initEvent('pbardone', true, true);
document.addEventListener('pbardone', function() {
    //code here 
});
//if progress bar reaches 100 dispatchEvent
if (document.querySelector(".progress-bar").style.width === 100 + "%")
{
    document.dispatchEvent(pBarEvent);
}
```

Now that piece of code is an example. If the document loads and its for instance at 50% it wont trigger until you add another event such as keydown or click. I dont want to do that I want to do.... "when" progress bar width equals 100% trigger it. Thats basically what needs to happen. So here is the code for the when statement so far (keep in mind its not the best looking one. As I dont normally do this but I wanted to keep this dynamic and who knows someone who later wants to do this can look at this question)

**when function**

```
function when(func)
{
    var nowActive = false;
    if (!typeof func === 'undefined')
    {
        func = new Function();
    }
    if (func)
    {
        nowActive = true;
        clearInterval(whenStatementTimer);
    }
    else 
    { 
        nowActive = false;
        var whenStatementTimer = setInterval(function() {
            switch(func)
            {
                case true: 
                {
                    nowActive = true;
                    when();
                    break;
                }
                case false: 
                {
                    nowActive = false;
                    when();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    if (nowActive === true)
    {
        func();
    }
}
```

Now this does not work when I go to try something like....

```
when(function() {
    SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadEvents.customEvents.progressBarFull(function() {
        alert("100%");
        SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadAds.LeadView.ChromeExtension.General.DynamicStyles.$.style("body", "background", "black");
    });
});
```

It does not trigger. I need help possibly getting this when statement to work. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix it? No errors get thrown but it never fires.

**edit based on answer**

**Function tried**

```
function when(currentValue)
{
    try
    {
        var o = {};
        o.currentValue = currentValue;
        o.do = function(func)
        {
            if (!typeof func === 'undefined')
            {
                func = new Function();
            }
            if (this.currentValue)
            {
                func();
            }
            else 
            {
                setTimeout(this.do(func), 100);
            }
        };
        return o;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

**used as**

```
when(true).do(function() { 
    SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadEvents.customEvents.progressBarFull(function() { 
        alert("This divs going through changes!!");
        SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadAds.LeadView.ChromeExtension.General.DynamicStyles.$.style(".div", "background", "black");
    });
});
```

This does not work. It never fires. But if I use a onclick listener as such it fires

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadEvents.customEvents.progressBarFull(function() { 
        alert("This divs going through changes!!");
        SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadAds.LeadView.ChromeExtension.General.DynamicStyles.$.style(".div", "background", "black");
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: I dont understand switch(func) {case true

Comment: Basically if the function work or if it does not. I did say Ive never made a function like this before.

Comment: Func is an function object; it hasnt a value.

Comment: Sample code of your's is working Check this http://jsbin.com/yiyexeyumi/edit?js,console

Comment: No. It gets fired off by other events. Example a progress bar reaches 100 when I press a key. But the when statement does not fire until I press a keybagain. Console.log must have its own listeners therefore triggering butbnot with the when statement.

Comment: So you want: when "this" is true do "that"

Comment: Yes. That way I dont have to register another clic event or keydown event. Itll fire only "when" the function does. Or when the condition is true.

Comment: I think my  mistake is the setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function when(statement){
   o={};
   o.statement=statement;
   o.do=function(func){
      awhen(this.statement,func);
   };
   return o;
}
function awhen(statement,func){
   if(eval(statement)){
      func();
   }else{
      window.setTimeout(function(){awhen(statement,func);},100);
   }
}
```

Use:

```
when("true").do(function(){});
```

It works now :) . Its important to put the condition in ""!

Comment: Yeah thats a point. But i think its readable. It uses the argument passed to create an object with a function inside. This object is returned so when() returns an object and .do() calls the function of the object

Comment: I understand what he is doing. But I need to keep the syntax to when(function() { /*code*/ });

Comment: You cannot check if a function is valid. But you can check if it returns true;

Comment: I redid it actually not it does not do anything whn I call SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadEvents.customEvents.progressBarFull(function() { alert("This div is going through changes!!"); SmartLeadJS.SmartLeadAds.LeadView.ChromeExtension.General.DynamicStyles.$.style(".div", "background", "black"); });}); It doesnt do anything.

Comment: I did some more experimenting with the function (the revised function is in my edit) and I now see it does work if I do something like... when(document.querySelector(".progress-bar") === 50 + "%").do(function() { alert("Worked"); }); 50% is what it starts out with.. Which I found is the problem. The function does not keep checking until it is true. So if I see whether the seekbar is 70% and dynamically change it from 50% to 70% dynamically it doesnt run because it does not keep checking. How can I do that?

Comment: Which explains why if I fire another event such as a click event after it changes to 100% it works but does not work when I use the when statement.

Comment: I think through the timeout the scope was changed so func and parameter where undefined. Ive changed it through adding a real function so that the scope isnt changed

Comment: Please check your keyboard; the TAB key may be broken. Normally it indents lines.

Comment: @user019911019019101901: Made another mistake :( . when you pass a condition a==1 it is checked if  a is 1 and just true or false is passed to the function. so the if(parameter) was always false because parameter=false. I improved it using eval. So you have to pass the condition as a string "a==1" so that it is passed trough the loop, and just executed in the if statement.

Comment: Last I checked mobile keyboards have space keys.

Comment: @torazaburo : ok, i thought it was readable enough, but i changed it